# How can i make rails models belongs_to using multiple foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

recently I have a migration that adds a `user_id` column to the watch_events tables. and thus I want to change the watch_event models to handle belongs_to but with multiple approach

```
  create_table 'users', force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer 'id'
    t.integer 'customer_id'
  end

  create_table 'watch_events', force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer 'customer_id'
    t.integer 'user_id'
  end
```

previously

```
class WatchEvent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :customer_id, primary_key: :customer_id
end
```

what I want:

- if `watch_event.customer_id` is present, i want to use `belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :customer_id, primary_key: :customer_id`
- if `watch_event.customer_id` is not present, i want to use normal `belongs_to :user`

how can I achieve this on the watch_event model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that Rails supports 'fallback foreign keys' on associations. However, you can write a simple wrapper for your problem. First, relate your `WatchEvent` class twice to the user model, using your two keys and two 'internal' association names (`:user_1` and `:user_2`). Then, add a 'virtual association reader' (`user`) and a 'virtual association setter' (`user=(new_user)`):

```
class WatchEvent < ApplicationRecord
  
  belongs_to :user_1,
             class_name: 'User',
             foreign_key: :customer_id

  belongs_to :user_2,
             class_name: 'User',
             foreign_key: :user_id
  
  def user
    user_1 || user_2
  end

  def user=(new_user)
    self.user_1 = new_user
  end

end
```

With this solution, the requirements "use `customer_id` to find user" and "use `user_id` as fallback foreign key if `customer_id` is `nil` or doesn't yield a result" is satisfied. It happens in the association reader method `user`. When there is a reader method, you'll need a setter method, which is `user=()`. Feel free to design the setter's internals as required, mine is just a suggestion.

BTW: You may need to re-add the declaration of the foreign `primary_key`. I omitted that for clarity.

Comment: this seems will do the trick for what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then what you are looking for is a [Polymorphic association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

If you see the code below, what it basically does is create two columns in the `watch_events` table, `watcher_type` and `watcher_id`. And the `belongs_to :watcher` then uses the `watcher_type` column to identify which model it should associate to,

```
create_table 'watch_events', force: :cascade do |t|
  t.references 'watcher', polymorphic: true, null: false
end

class WatchEvent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :watcher, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: that's not what i mean. the thing is i want to move from
`belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :customer_id, primary_key: :customer_id` to
`belongs_to :user`
but due to the backward compatibility, the old watch_events data will have the user_id null